# how to import google play services from library project?

Tags: java, android

sir, is there any way by which we can use the library of library projects in main project .. i mean to say i m working on an application in which i have three applications as library project for my main application. and each library project consist of google play service library . now my question is that how can i use that library in my main project as individual library project have ad banner implemented and each have  interstitial ads in it. now i want that when ever i click on one of those application there ads mobs should work . i googled a lot but haven’t found  anything useful...kindly help me ...i must admit that i m new in android programming.

Even i have declared the bellow code in my main projects manifest

Error which i m getting :-

```
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dummmmyyyy/com.library.project.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #187: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #187: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.library.project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     ... 11 more
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dummmmyyyy-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.dummmmyyyy-1, /system/lib]]
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
07-14 13:55:22.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
```

Any help would be appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to call me sir.. the library project needs to be added to your build path: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: hey erik , thanks for your reply ..i have already added all the three separate projects as library in my main project. Is there any way that i can use the google play service library of each project in my main project so that i can be able to show the functionality of interstitial ads and adsmob banner of each app through my main project